# Quasar fiber - difference between join() and get()

Tags: java, fiber, fibers, quasar, quasar-framework

The title says it all. There's no explicit instructions on these two methods as to which should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods wait for the fibre to complete.  The `get()` method returns the result, and the `join()` method doesn't.

Why does the API have both methods?  Because the respective interfaces (`Future` and `Joinable`) require both.

Which to use?  Which ever does what you need!